# Basic Curl to PHP Conversion

Tags: php, curl, stripe-payments

I'm trying to figure out how to do this CURL command:

```
curl https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files \
  -u sk_test_OCHANGEDPcDr0: \
  -F purpose=identity_document \
  -F file="@/path/to/a/file.jpg"
```

In PHP, I'm using this PHP script:
https://github.com/php-mod/curl

And tried this:

```
$curl->setBasicAuthentication('-u', 'sk_live_CHANGED');
$curl->post('https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files', array(
        'purpose' => 'dispute_evidence',
        'file' => $targetFile,
    ));
```

But I think the syntax is completely wrong, I'm really new to curl and don't understand what all the different -u and -F commands PHP equivalents are.

Comment: I know what they mean, I can't figure out the syntax for the PHP equivalent

Comment: Postman is an interface to HTTP/API request and has a feature that shows several "copies" of the request in curl, PHP, Python among other alternatives: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Comment: Why do you have `-u` in the arguments to `setBasicAuthentication`? The first argument should be the username, the second argument should be the password.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to try something like this:

```
$headers = array(
  'Authorization: Bearer ' . $your_api_key,
  'Content-Type: multipart/form-data'
);

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files',
  CURLOPT_POST => true,
  CURLOPT_INFILESIZE => '10000',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    'purpose' => 'dispute_evidence',
    'file' => '@' . realpath($path_to_file)
  )
));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

EDIT: Alternatively, you can upload files directly from the browser [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/captainapollo/d8yd3761/).

Comment: What about setting the API key?

Comment: I'm getting this error with that code:

"error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "Invalid hash",
    "param": "file"
  }

the file is uploading to the server

Comment: It's uploading to the server but not transfering over to stripe

Answer (score 1):

The `-u username:password` option translates to:

```
$curl->setBasicAuthentication('username', 'password');
```

To upload a file, you need to put `@` before the filename, just like in the `curl` command.

```
$curl->post('https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files', array(
    'purpose' => 'dispute_evidence',
    'file' => '@' . $targetFile,
));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a functional `curl` command invocation, you can get what you are after by adding the `--libcurl filename.c` option.

This will generate a C program to do what your command line did.  Though you are after PHP and not C, this is still useful because they both use the same names for various options.